# How to contact strings in RythmPlay template engine?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, rythm

```
@str .length = @str.length()
```

outputs

```
abcde .length = 5
```

I tried various escaping techniques, but didn't find the correct one. How do I output

```
abcde.length = 5
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [migration tutorial](http://software-lgl.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/step-by-step-migrate-your-groovy.html) covers it:

```
Jack is a @(vice)maniac.
```